# Rollup external dependency with subfolder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, rollupjs

I tried searching for something relevant but couldn't find anything helpful.

I have React application generated with the Vite tool. That react application consumes a private package that is a wrapper to the MUI library and provides some custom components on top.

I want to have this package cached as UMD packaged hosted on private CDN. So far I've been successfully able to make this work on a simpler package, which has only a base path as export. But with this MUI wrapper, it's not working like that.

The Vite config is as follows

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      external:  [
        'react', 
        'react-dom',
        'simple-package',
        /^mui-wrapper.*/g,
      ],
      output: {
        format: 'iife',
        globals: {
          'react': 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          'simple-package': 'simplepackage',
          'mui-wrapper': 'muiwrapper'
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

The app is building and I can confirm that those packages are not included in the build. They are added as script URLs which I can verify, and I can access them from the 'globalThis' object in the browser.

As I mentioned the simple one is working but when I try to do this

```js
import { createTheme } from 'mui-wrapper/theme/theme'
```

I get error
**index-82fbfd72.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: theme is not defined**

I can verify that
**globalThis.muiwrapper.theme.theme.createTheme** is indeed defined

I suspect it's something to do with the import path, but I am not all that familiar with the those exports.